# MIME type application/octet-stream

Tags: mime

Смотрю исходный код сайта одного российского тур-оператора в Google Chrome. Вижу такое:

[image]

Возникло два вопроса:

1. Что это?
2. Зачем это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используется для обозначения того, что тело содержит бинарные данные. Набор возможных параметров включает следующие (но не ограничивается ими):

`TYPE` -- обобщенный тип или категория двоичных данных, эта информация больше предназначена для получателя, чем для автоматической обработки.

`PADDING` -- число заполняющих битов, добавленных к битовому потоку, содержащему данные, для формирования байтно-ориентированных данных. Полезно при заключении в тело битового потока, когда общее число битов не кратно восьми, то есть, размеру байта.

Думаю, что вопрос зачем это уже совсем глупый =)

[octet-stream](http://www.google.ru/search?q=octet-stream)

Comment: Хорошо. Общая информация к сведению принята. Теперь двинемся вглубь. Зачем вместо нормальной картинки передавать нечто такое, что вызывает в хроме подобное сообщение? Тем более, что ничего особенного в картинках нет. Например, вот: http://clck.ru/1KOz9

Comment: Примеров может для использования много! К примеру, вы когда-нибудь передавали картинку в бейс46? Вот вам пример использования =) бинарники всегда шустрее отрабатывают =) но правда в весе можно, конечно, что-то потерять =( еще может быть как вариант теоретически можно бинарником заряжать шрифты, или недостоющие библеотеки =) как-то так =)